# A quick method to make beveled gaps?

Tags: modeling, workflow

So I am trying to get from figure 1 to figure 2 in the image below, but the way I do it takes a lot longer than I would like so I'm interested in other methods to achieve this affect to help my workflow. [image]

However I need the method to work with more advanced shapes. I am hoping there is a way to select a loop that I want to bevel inward as the first step or maybe something better, so please share your methods for achieving something like this and it must work with very advanced shapes for example the one in the figure below.V
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can go from left to right in the 1-st screenshot quicker than in 3 actions (bevel, scale along normals, bevel). Second part of the question is unclear, how is gun related, it "must work with advanced shapes" etc. Advanced shapes start from simple shapes.

Comment: By advanced shapes I mean a method to pretty much add a beveled gap to any mesh, the picture was just to illustrate I need it to work on things other than a cube. Lets say I wanted to add a beveled gap to some point on the handle of the gun, I would need a method that would work for that. The question is not gun related.